# Why inside ref's change behaves inconsistantly from inside to outside?

Tags: python

```py
def foo(l):
   r.append(l)
   l[0], l[1] = l[1], l[0] 
   r.append(l)

r = []
l = [0, 1]
print(l);
foo(l)
print(l);
print(r);
```

print out:

```py
[0, 1]
[1, 0]
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
```

As I know python passes arguments by assignments, as a new ref to the outer `[0, 1]`, the inner `l` with swap like this does not create a new object but change the object the inner refers to, so as the outer print of `l` acts similarly the behaviour was assumpted.

But the pair of `r.append(l)` seems add the object with the same content each time. Is is beacase of features like lazy loading or some?

Of course, this may be solved by using methods like `r.append(x for x in l)`, which in my opinion, add a new list object to `r`. But still, I want to figure out what is the behvaiour defined in python that we add an item (same ref to an object) to a list, and what happened when we ask for the list content.

Comment: There is only ever one list `l`, references to it are being passed around and appended to other lists but it's always the same object. Is it the line `l[0], l[1] = l[1], l[0]` that you are expecting to be creating a new list?

Comment: That swap does not create a new object, hence all it's reference is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question. Let's break down what is happening.

One of the tools you have when you get questions like this is the [`id` built-in function.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) `id` is a way of checking whether the object is the same as a previous one or not.

Let's use `id` in your code.

```py
def foo(l):
   print("The ID of r in the function foo is {}".format(id(r)))
   print("The ID of l in the function foo is {}".format(id(l)))

   r.append(l)
   print("The ID of r in the function foo after the append is {}".format(id(r)))
   print("The ID of the the items in r: {}, after first append".format(id(r[0])))
   l[0], l[1] = l[1], l[0]
   print("The ID of l in the function foo after the swap is {}".format(id(l)))
 
   r.append(l)
   print("The ID of r in the function foo after second append is {}".format(id(r)))
   print("The ID of the the items in r: {}, {} after second append".format(id(r[0]), id(r[1])))


r = []
print("The ID of r in the beginning is {}".format(id(r)))
l = [0, 1]
print("The ID of l in the beginning is {}".format(id(l)))
print(l)
foo(l)
print(l)
print("The ID of l after the foo call is {}".format(id(l)))

print(r)
print("The ID of r after the foo call is {}".format(id(r)))
print("The ID of the the items in r: {}, {}".format(id(r[0]), id(r[1])))
```

My output (yours will vary) is:

```
The ID of r in the beginning is 4374077736
The ID of l in the beginning is 4374122152
[0, 1]
The ID of r in the function foo is 4374077736
The ID of l in the function foo is 4374122152
The ID of r in the function foo after the append is 4374077736
The ID of the the items in r: 4374122152, after first append
The ID of l in the function foo after the swap is 4374122152
The ID of r in the function foo after second append is 4374077736
The ID of the the items in r: 4374122152, 4374122152 after second append
[1, 0]
The ID of l after the foo call is 4374122152
[[1, 0], [1, 0]]
The ID of r after the foo call is 4374077736
The ID of the the items in r: 4374122152, 4374122152
```

What this tells us is that there is always only 2 variables here.

Even *within* `r`. You are appending *the same object* twice. And this object can be changed externally as well.

So whenever it changes, it *changes within your containing list* as well.

Each item in `r` is pointing to **the same** `l`.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are not familiar with Python, I tried to write a self-explainatory C++ code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    void setValue(int value) {
        this->value = value;
    }

    int getValue() {
        return this->value;
    }
private:
    int value;
};

int main() {
    vector<A*> list;
    A* obj = new A();

    obj->setValue(1);
    list.push_back(obj);
    obj->setValue(2);
    list.push_back(obj);
    obj->setValue(3);
    list.push_back(obj);

    for (auto item : list) {
        cout << item->getValue() << endl;
    }
}
```

prints out:

```
3
3
3
```

It's almost the same thing that was done with Python in question.